# Remove group based on factor in other column

Tags: r, dataframe, conditional-statements

I would like to remove the rows of the entire group based on the numbering of the count and id column.

```
    id count  group
1  244     1  black
2  244     2  black
3  244     3  black
4  333     1  black
5  333     2  black
6  582     1 yellow
7  582     2 yellow
8  582     3 yellow
9  676    10 yellow
10 676    11 yellow
11 676    12 yellow
```

For example, group black has two id factors (`244` and `333`) which both start with count `1` (`1, 2, 3` and `1, 2` respectively).

However, group yellow has also two id factors (`582` and `676`), but its second id `676` does *not* start with count `1` (it starts with `10`). Therefore, I would like to remove *all* rows of yellow in the data frame.

Desired output:

```
   id count group
1 244     1 black
2 244     2 black
3 244     3 black
4 333     1 black
5 333     2 black
```

Code to create data frame:

```
id = as.factor(c(244, 244, 244, 333, 333, 
                 582, 582, 582, 676, 676, 676))   
count = c(1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 10, 11, 12) 
group = as.factor(c("black", "black", "black", "black", "black", 
                    "yellow", "yellow","yellow", "yellow", "yellow", "yellow"))  
df = data.frame(id, count, group)
```

I'm scratching my head on how to achieve this objective, but it's not clicking with me.

**Updated example**

```
    id      id2 count  group
1  244 81308991     1  black
2  244 97881213     2  black
3  244 84929200     3  black
4  333 59742977     1  black
5  333 25048598     2  black
6  582 30902503     1 yellow
7  582 62598100     2 yellow
8  582 33639927     3 yellow
9  676 13531041    10 yellow
10 676 15731681    11 yellow
11 676 49423609    12 yellow
```

Code:

```
id = as.factor(c(244, 244, 244, 333, 333, 
                 582, 582, 582, 676, 676, 676))     
id2 = as.factor(c(81308991, 97881213, 84929200, 59742977, 25048598, 
                  30902503, 62598100, 33639927, 13531041, 15731681, 49423609))  
count = c(1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 10, 11, 12) 
group = as.factor(c("black", "black", "black", "black", "black", 
                    "yellow", "yellow","yellow", "yellow", "yellow", "yellow"))  
df = data.frame(id, id2, count, group)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with just base R by using `ave`. The trick is to find out `min` value of `count` for sub-groups by `id` and then to find out the `max` for the the computed `min` again by `group`. If both values are 1, you want to retain them.

```
df[ave(ave(df$count, df$id, FUN = min), df$group, FUN = max) == 1,]
#   id count group
#1 244     1 black
#2 244     2 black
#3 244     3 black
#4 333     1 black
#5 333     2 black
```

*NOTE*: As Frank commented, if the same `id` can appear in multiple `group`, be sure to use `df$id` as well as `df$group` in the inner `ave`

Comment: Nice answer. If the same id can appear in multiple groups, they'd want to use both df$id and df$group in the inner `ave`.

Comment: Thank you for your elegant solution! It seems that the id does appear in multiple groups. I tried your suggestion as follows: `df[ave(ave(df$count, df$id, df$group, FUN = min), df$group, FUN = max) == 1,]`, but I get the following error: `Error in split.default(x, g) : group length is 0 but data length > 0`

Comment: The data set is quite large (around 5 million rows), so I am not sure how to identify the problematic records unfortunately. However, maybe this could help: there is another column in my data set `id2` which, together with `id`, forms the actual unique identifier (please see the update in my question if you feel this additional column could provide another solution).  Thanks again!

Comment: @apples-oranges, you mean something like: `df[ave(ave(df$count, paste(df$id, df$id2), df$group, FUN = min), df$group, FUN = max) == 1,]`

Comment: I think your solution is actually correct, but it gives me a memory error: `Error: cannot allocate vector of size 13512.5 Gb`. Thank you for your efforts, appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

We need to first compute whether there is a group not starting with 1, and then filter the whole data.frame. Here's is non-optimal solution with dplyr

```
library(dplyr)
group_by(df, group, id) %>% 
  ## see what group + id doesn't start with 1
  mutate(s = ifelse(first(count) != 1, 1, 0)) %>% 
  ## generalize to the whole group
  group_by(group) %>% 
  mutate(s = sum(s)) %>% 
  ## filter out groups
  filter(s == 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `filter()` function in the `dplyr` package by loading the `tidyverse`

```
library(tidyverse)
df1 <- df %>%
  filter(group != "yellow")

> df1
   id count group
 1 244     1 black
 2 244     2 black
 3 244     3 black
 4 333     1 black
 5 333     2 black
```